# Odd execution benchmark while printing stack trace and measuring function execution

Tags: c++

I want to have some simple instrumentation, to print function call stack and measure the time taken by each function. To that end, I have

```
#define STACK_TRACE_ENABLED 1

struct trace_t {
    std::string func_name;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end;
};

using stack_trace_t = std::vector<trace_t>;
auto stack_trace = stack_trace_t{};

void print_top_of_trace() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    duration<double, std::nano> t = stack_trace.back().end - stack_trace.back().begin;
    std::cout << "## " << std::setw(50) << stack_trace.back().func_name 
              << " took " << std::setw(16)  << t.count() 
              << " nanoseconds ##\n";
}

struct tracer {
    tracer(std::string fn) 
    :begin{std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()}
    {
        stack_trace.push_back(trace_t{fn, begin, end});
    }

    ~tracer() {
        stack_trace[stack_trace.size() - 1].end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        print_top_of_trace();
        stack_trace.pop_back();
    }

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end;
};
```

and some macros to ease the use:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define ADD_STACK_TRACE_(func_name) tracer __ny_tracer(func_name);
#define ADD_STACK_TRACE ADD_STACK_TRACE_(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
#else
#define ADD_STACK_TRACE_(func_name) (void)(0);
#define ADD_STACK_TRACE ADD_STACK_TRACE_(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)
#endif
```

Then I have couple of functions to measure. You basically need to add `ADD_STACK_TRACE` as the first line in your functions. Full working example can be seen in [godbolt](https://st.godbolt.org/z/3_vqvH). Remaining part basically looks like:

```
constexpr auto sin = [](float x) {
    ADD_STACK_TRACE
    return x  - 
    ((x * x * x) / 6.0f) + 
    ((x * x * x * x * x) / 120.0f) -
    ((x * x * x * x * x * x * x) / 5040.0f);
};

constexpr auto cos = [](float x) {
    ADD_STACK_TRACE
    return 1.0f  - 
    ((x * x) / 2.0f) + 
    ((x * x * x * x) / 24.0f) -
    ((x * x * x * x * x * x) / 720.0f);
};

float sum(float i1, float i2) {
    ADD_STACK_TRACE
    return i1 + i2;
}

float tan(float f) {
    ADD_STACK_TRACE
    return sin(f) / cos(f);
}

int main() {
    ADD_STACK_TRACE
    float param = sum(44.0f, 1.0f) * PI / 180.0f;
    return tan(param);
}
```

Currently, I get the following output:

```
##                            float sum(float, float) took             1442 nanoseconds ##

##    auto (anonymous class)::operator()(float) const took             2257 nanoseconds ##

##    auto (anonymous class)::operator()(float) const took              118 nanoseconds ##

##                                   float tan(float) took             4689 nanoseconds ##

##                                         int main() took            44182 nanoseconds ##
```

which looks weird to me. `sin` and `cos` both uses Taylor expansion and I can't see a reason why they should differ so much in execution time. Indeed, if I remove `ADD_STACK_TRACE` from `tan`, I get the following output:

```
##                            float sum(float, float) took             1324 nanoseconds ##

##    auto (anonymous class)::operator()(float) const took              169 nanoseconds ##

##    auto (anonymous class)::operator()(float) const took              124 nanoseconds ##

##                                         int main() took            33660 nanoseconds ##
```

As you can see, this shows `sin` and `cos` to be pretty close. This made me think of two ways that this could go wrong. It might be that my instrumentation code actually outweighs the actual function executions I am trying to measure. Other option might be that there is something terribly wrong with my instrumentation logic. Of course, it could be both. In short, what is the problem here?

> PS: I would normally use a benchmarking library. This is for my own experimentation with similar ideas.

EDIT:
After both suggestions to reserve some inital capacity, I changed the code as follows. First, I made sure that sampling for begin happens at the end of constructor and sampling stops at the beginning of the constructor:

```
tracer(std::string fn)
    {
        stack_trace.push_back(trace_t{fn, begin, end});
        stack_trace[stack_trace.size() - 1].begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }

    ~tracer() {
        stack_trace[stack_trace.size() - 1].end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        print_top_of_trace();
        stack_trace.pop_back();
    }
```

and I also reserved capacity at the start of main using `stack_trace.reserve(1000)`. Current results look more promising.

```
##                            float sum(float, float) took              178 nanoseconds ##

##    auto (anonymous class)::operator()(float) const took               67 nanoseconds ##

##    auto (anonymous class)::operator()(float) const took               70 nanoseconds ##

##                                   float tan(float) took             2539 nanoseconds ##

##                                         int main() took            33014 nanoseconds ##
```

But still, there is something wrong in my logic I believe. There is so much difference between the time for `main` and time for `tan`, for example. Can you explain this? Inevitably, their measurements include all the `push_back` and `pop_back` of previous stack traces, as an example.

Comment: stack_trace  could make some vector allocation between function calls. Try it with some initial capacity.

Comment: tracer(std::string fn) change this tracer(const std::string &fn); avoid string copy operation for passing parameter. and you dont need begin, end members for tracer class.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<T>` documentation says :

> The storage of the vector is handled automatically, being expanded and
>   contracted as needed.

How to prevent is

> Reallocations are usually costly operations in terms of performance.
>   The reserve() function can be used to eliminate reallocations if the
>   number of elements is known beforehand.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

You are using global single vector instance and storing your measurements in it, so while you are pushing, after a while, vector needs to be resized, this affects your performance measurement.

So, try this :

```
constexpr auto sin = [](float x) {
    ADD_STACK_TRACE
    return x  - 
    ((x * x * x) / 6.0f) + 
    ((x * x * x * x * x) / 120.0f) -
    ((x * x * x * x * x * x * x) / 5040.0f);
};

constexpr auto cos = [](float x) {
    ADD_STACK_TRACE
    return 1.0f  - 
    ((x * x) / 2.0f) + 
    ((x * x * x * x) / 24.0f) -
    ((x * x * x * x * x * x) / 720.0f);
};

float sum(float i1, float i2) {
    ADD_STACK_TRACE
    return i1 + i2;
}

float tan(float f) {
    ADD_STACK_TRACE
    return sin(f) / cos(f);
}

int main() {
    // This prevents re-allocation until 1000 elements inserted
    stack_trace.reserve( 1000 ); 
    ADD_STACK_TRACE
    float param = sum(44.0f, 1.0f) * PI / 180.0f;
    return tan(param);
}
```

tan function measurement seems weird but not.

- tan( float ) called
- sin( f ) called
- ADD_STACK_TRACE
- calculation
- cos( f ) called
- ADD_STACK_TRACE
- calculation
- division

so `tan(float)` accumulates times required to computation and also execution ADD_STACK_TRACE statements so it gives weird outputs because ADD_STACK_TRACE statements takes time.

Comment: This helps, but I feel like there is something(s) else wrong with my tracing logic. Could you see any more suggestions? I edited the question.

Comment: I dont know why `main()` takes too much, maybe someone else can answer that

Comment: Indeed,  I feel like `main` should have one extra overhead of `ADD_STACK_TRACE` compared to `tan` but they are way off.